# Firebase messaging "the site has been updated in background"

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I've got a problem. When getting a notification in my service worker:

```
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
  angularClient.postMessage(payload.data);
});
```

How can I prevent the browser from showing notification that says:

> the site has been updated in background

What I do is sending a message to my service where the notification will be showed. For now it shows two notifications. One from my service which is fine and another saying "the site... ".

Answer (score 8):

You *MUST* show a notification when onBackgroundMessage is called and make sure your return the promise from `registration.showNotification('title', {body: 'message'})`

The reason for this is that web push doesn't support silent messages.

Comment: this is by far the easiest solution

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this notification in addition to the one I created myself. Spent two days trying to fix it. This is the code that worked for me:

```
self.addEventListener('push', async function(event) {
    event.waitUntil(
        self.registration.showNotification('title', {
          body: 'body'
        })
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

firebase v10 answer, you have to return the show notification promise

```
import { getMessaging, onBackgroundMessage } from 'firebase/messaging/sw'
onBackgroundMessage(getMessaging(app), payload => {
    const { title, body } = payload.data

    return (
        self.registration
            .showNotification(title, { body })
    )
})
```