Getting additional web notification with content "This site has been updated in the background" when using web fcm in angular
I have created a service worker in angular where I have subscribed the background notification but every time a notification is received in the browser an additional notification is also triggered with content This site has been updated in the background. I think additional notification is triggered from chrome browser when it does not receive a call back for the web notification triggered.
My service worker looks like
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.3/firebase-app-compat.js");
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.3/firebase-messaging-compat.js");

firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: API_KEY,
  authDomain: AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: APP_ID,
  measurementId: MEASUREMENT_ID
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function(payload) {
  const notificationTitle = payload.data.title;
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: payload.data.body,
    icon: '/firebase-logo.png'
  };

  self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
});


I am triggering the notification from Ruby on rails backend where I am using FCM gem version 2.0 with the body
{
      'token': token,
      'data': {
        payload: {
          data: {
            notification_id: notification_id,
            title: title,
            body: description,
            image_url: image_url,
          }
        }.to_json
      },
      'webpush': {
        headers: {
          "Urgency": "high",
          image: image_url
        },
        data: {
          notification_id: notification_id,
          title: title,
          body: description,
          image_url: image_url
        fcm_options: {
          link: link
        }
      }

I have tried to find the point where this notification is generated but so for I came to this conclusion that this notification is instantly triggered.

Seems like the general suggestion for these dual notifications is to add an event listener and use waitUntil: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59126830/1978251 https://stackoverflow.com/a/78732552/1978251 https://stackoverflow.com/a/34592882/1978251 https://stackoverflow.com/a/70958952/1978251

The problem is that, when you receive the push event, you need to use event.waitUntil() to display the notification and you must always display at least one notification, otherwise that strange message is displayed.
